# why biosphere activities may appear in the technosphere matrix?

Tags: brightway

I was testing how to add a new "activity" to my biosphere3 matrix in brightway, and I got a new column in my technosphere matrix that I was not expecting, (corresponding to the id of my new biosphere node). Is this behaviour the expected one ?. Not that I want to stick to traditions, but usually columns in the technosphere matrix are not "elementary flows". I am using bw2calc version (2.0.DEV1) and bw2data version (4.0.DEV1)

Here some code to try to reproduce this behaviour:

```
b3 = bw2data.Database('biosphere3')

uwva_node = b3.new_activity(code='uwva_ppp',
            name='utility weighted value added (PPP)',
            categories=('social',),
            unit = 'Meuro_ppp',
            )
uwva_node.save()
```

```
act1_key=('test_db','activity_1')

biosphere_exchange_1={'amount':2,
                    'input':uwva_node.key,
                    'output':act1_key,
                    'type':'biosphere',
                    'uncertainty type': 0}

production_exchange_1={'amount':2,
                     'input':act1_key,
                     'output':act1_key,
                     'type':'production',
                     'uncertainty type':0}

act_1_dict={'name':'test_activity_1',
 'unit':'megajoule',
 'exchanges':[production_exchange_1,biosphere_exchange_1]}

act2_key=('test_db','activity_2')

production_exchange_2={'amount':10,
                     'input':act2_key,
                     'output':act2_key,
                     'type':'production',
                     'uncertainty type':0}

technosphere_exchange_1={
    'amount':10, # 
    'input':act1_key,
    'output':act2_key,
    'type':'technosphere',
}

act_2_dict={'name':'test_activity_2',
            'unit':'megajoule',
            'exchanges':[production_exchange_2,technosphere_exchange_1]}

database_dict={act1_key:act_1_dict,
               act2_key:act_2_dict}

db=bw2data.Database('test_db')

db.write(database_dict)
```

if I calculate the inventory I get a technosphere matrix with 3 columns. And my new biosphere activity is on the technosphere matrix as well.

```
act2 = bw2data.get_activity(act2_key)

lca = bw2calc.LCA({act2:1})

lca.lci()

lca.technosphere_matrix.todense()

assert uwva_node.id in lca.dicts.activity
assert uwva_node.id in lca.dicts.biosphere
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you created `uwva_node`, you didn't tell Brightway what `type` it was, so it assumed it was a normal activity that should fit into the technosphere. As such, because you didn't give it a production exchange, it [assumed that there was an implicit production amount](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2-data/blob/3aa42d93cb6ded0e8a8cb4162c052995ac7060d3/bw2data/backends/base.py#L712) of `1`, which is what you see in the technosphere.

You can fix this by specifying the new activity type to anything other than `process`, e.g.

```
uwva_node = b3.new_activity(code='uwva_ppp',
        name='utility weighted value added (PPP)',
        categories=('social',),
        unit = 'Meuro_ppp',
        type="social",
)
```